# How to tighten/fix ice-maker's drainage tube connector?

Tags: water, refrigerator

On the back of our fridge is a drainage tube (I assume it's for the ice maker; correct me if i'm wrong). Whenever water drains out of it, it leaks. I've identified that the source of the problem is a sort of coupler in the middle of the tube. (I'm not sure what it's called)

[image: coupler thingy for fridge]

I've fiddled with it a little bit but I can't seem to get it to stop leaking. Is there a trick to tighten it? Or should I buy a new one? (If so, anyone know where I can get one?)

Comment: (if someone could retag this if appropriate that would be great. I was sort of at a loss as to what to tag it with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind there is a lot of pressure in the water line. I don't like using the plastic tubing that comes with the fridges, I use copper lines only. I would change the tubing from that connector to the water line with 1/4" copper tubing and a brass compression fitting to replace that plastic one. [A compression fitting like this one](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-25ecodZ5yc1v/R-100617058/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=compression%20fitting&storeId=10051) will do nicely.A brass insert, [like this one](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-25ecodZ5yc1v/R-100638201/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=commpression&storeId=10051) is used to connect the plastic pipe to one side.
[image]
[image]

Comment: We just went to Ace Hardware and the guy told us the same thing. We got the same exact parts! Turns out though, the problem was more than just the connector; it leaked at the exit from the fridge, so we'll definitely replace it with copper tubing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We know them as "John Guest" (The Brand Name) fittings and they are prone to leaking as its only an o-ring sealing the fitting to the pipe, if the pipe has a scratch on it or isn't fully inserted it can leak.

They also can be fitted with a collar clamp that holds the release mech ( the red part in this fitting) from accidentally being pushed down and releasing the pipe from the fitting.

[image: The Locking Clamp]

You can also get brass fitting for use with "John Guest" pipe, you can see them at the [offical website](http://www.johnguest.co.uk/Home/applications/beverages-and-drinks-dispense/Brass-Fittings-for-Beverage-Dispense.aspx).

Comment: In addition to UNECS's good suggestion, if re-cutting the line (to fix scratch issue) nor adjusting the clamp fitting fix the issue, replacing the connector is an additional quick fix.  Watts also makes these (http://www.watts.com/pages/_products_details.asp?pid=6681), and they sell at most hardware stores.